# React Router Param bug

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

EDIT: I found the issue, I went ahead and double checked my Header Component. I was using a relative path "login" as opposed to an absolute path "/login". When I switched from "login" to "/login" the issue was fixed.

I am having issues with react router. I have the App Class component where I locate all my routes. The issue is that when I go to the "Products" page (http://localhost:3000/products) I can link directly to the  "ProductPage" where I get the route "http://localhost:3000/products/Scotts"; however when I navigate from that route to another route insted for example the "LoginPage" I get the following route "http://localhost:3000/products/login" as opposed to "http://localhost:3000/login". I will share the important code snippets below.

```
 <Router> 
        <div className="App">
          <ScrollToTop />
            <Header/>  
            <Switch >
              <Route exact path="/" component={ LandingPage }/>

          <Route  exact path="/login" component={ LoginPage }/>

              <Route  exact path="/products" component={ Products }/>
              <Route 
                exact 
                path="/products/:product"
                render={props => {
                  return <ProductPage {...props} />;
                }} 
              /> 

              <Route path="resetPassword/:id" component={ChangePassword} />
            </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Here I am linking from the Products route to the Product's single page route:

```
 {currentProducts.map(item => {
                const { image, title, price, stock } = item;
                return (
                    <div className="product-wrap" key={uuid()}>
                        <Link 
                            to={{
                                pathname: `${location.pathname}/${item.title}`,
                                state: {
                                    item: item,
                                    inStock: stock
                                }
                            }}
                            >
                            <div>
                                <div className="product">
                                    <div className="circle">
                                        <img alt="item" src={image} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                        <div
                            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
                            className="title"
                        >
                            {title}
                        </div>
                        <div
                            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
                            className="price"
                        >
                            ${price}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include *how* you're navigating from "/products/Scotts" to "/products/login"? By that I mean, can you include the component/code that does it. We've no idea if there's a link with a bad `to` prop, or if you're just doing something funny with a `history.push`. Do you have more than one `Router`?

Comment: @DrewReese Actually I was able to fix it afterwards but thank you I appreciate your help :)

Comment: May I suggest then you either delete this post, or answer it yourself with your solution so it may help others in case they have the same/similar issue?

Comment: @DrewReese Done.